# Pandas - How to groupby a ratio based on a condition in multiple binary columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am curious to see if someone has a solution to this problem using purely pandas, and not for loops as am doing. The current solution scales exponentially to the number of parameters I am grouping by.

So, initially I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
        theday   device  event1  event2
0   2019-02-21  desktop       0       0
1   2019-02-22  desktop       1       1
2   2019-02-23  desktop       0       0
3   2019-02-24  desktop       1       1
4   2019-02-21    other       0       0
5   2019-02-22    other       1       1
6   2019-02-23    other       0       0
7   2019-02-24    other       1       1
8   2019-02-21  desktop       0       1
9   2019-02-22  desktop       1       0
10  2019-02-23    other       0       1
11  2019-02-24    other       1       0
12  2019-02-21  desktop       0       1
13  2019-02-22  desktop       1       0
14  2019-02-23    other       0       1
15  2019-02-24    other       1       0
```

You can generate the dataframe with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
d = {'theday': ['2019-02-21','2019-02-22', '2019-02-23', '2019-02-24','2019-02-21','2019-02-22', '2019-02-23', '2019-02-24', '2019-02-21','2019-02-22', '2019-02-23', '2019-02-24', '2019-02-21','2019-02-22', '2019-02-23', '2019-02-24'], 'device': ['desktop', 'desktop','desktop','desktop', 'other','other','other','other', 'desktop','desktop', 'other','other', 'desktop','desktop', 'other','other' ], 'event1': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'event2': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Each row represent a user. So, I want to calculate for every given day and device, what is the ratio of users that have seen event 1 and also have seen event 2, divided by the number of users that have seen only event1. To put it in an equation: `conversion = number_users_seen1_and_seen2 / number_users_seen1`.

Seeing event1 and event2 means that the user has a "1" in the column `event1` and a "1" in the column `event2`. And seeing event 1 means that the user has a "1" in the column `event1`.

My solution function for that is as follow:

```py
def get_ratios(df, e1, e2):

    temp_list = []
    for device in df['device'].unique(): # iterate through devices
        for theday in df['theday'].unique(): # iterate throug days
            current_df = df[(df['theday'] == theday) & (df['device'] == device)]
            if len(current_df[current_df[e1] == 1]) == 0: 
                conversion = 0 
            else: 
                conversion = len(current_df[(current_df[e1] == 1) & (current_df[e2] == 1)]) /len(current_df[current_df[e1] == 1]) 

            temp_dict = {"theday": theday, "device": device, "conversion": conversion}
            temp_list.append(temp_dict)

    return pd.DataFrame(temp_list)
```

If I do `get_ratios(df, "event1", "event2")` I get:

```
   conversion   device      theday
0    0.000000  desktop  2019-02-21
1    0.333333  desktop  2019-02-22
2    0.000000  desktop  2019-02-23
3    1.000000  desktop  2019-02-24
4    0.000000    other  2019-02-21
5    1.000000    other  2019-02-22
6    0.000000    other  2019-02-23
7    0.333333    other  2019-02-24
```

Theare are a few problems with this approach:

(1) The function currently only supports `theday` and `device`, but if I want to include more parameters, I will need to modify the code.

(2) The function runtime scales really bad with the number of parameters I am grouping by (exponentially).

(3) I am performing part of the logic outside of pandas.

My question is then, could I achieve the same without the for loops but only with pandas specific functions?

Comment: what is event 1 or event 2? I am not following... also please edit you original dataframe to a smaller subset so that we can paste it into our IDE easily, thanks

Comment: sorry but its impossible following your calcul to have conversion < 1, then conversion = (user1+user2)/user1  or (1 + user2/user1)

Comment: @Frenchy, I do not get what you are talking about. But to be clear, I am not displaying the full data-frame there, these are just for illustrating the general problem.

Comment: @aws_apprentice I clarified further, hope it helps.

Comment: ok...i am talking about your result in display dataframe, following your explanation its impossible to have conversion < 1

Comment: @Frenchy The conversion is equal to the users (rows) that have seen both events, divided by the users that have seen AT LEAST the first event. So you can obviously have a conversion that is <= 1. For instance: 300 users have seen event 1 (have 1 in event 1 column), but out of those only 200 have seen also event 2 (have 1 in both event 1 and event 2 columns) . That gives conversion = 200 / 300 which is < 1

Comment: I have added the question putting a complete dummy example. Please take a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though @Tox answer worked out in the toy example I posted, it did not in a bigger dataset. The issue is that it is grouping before checking if a given row has the two events. The following works:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

d = {'theday': ['2019-02-21','2019-02-22', '2019-02-23', '2019-02-24','2019-02-21','2019-02-22', '2019-02-23', '2019-02-24', '2019-02-21','2019-02-22', '2019-02-23', '2019-02-24', '2019-02-21','2019-02-22', '2019-02-23', '2019-02-24'], 'device': ['desktop', 'desktop','desktop','desktop', 'other','other','other','other', 'desktop','desktop', 'other','other', 'desktop','desktop', 'other','other' ], 'event1': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'event2': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['both'] = ((df["event1"] == 1) & (df["event2"] == 1)).astype('int')
df_grouped = df.groupby(['theday', 'device']).sum().reset_index()
df_grouped['conversion'] = (df_grouped['both'] / df_grouped["event1"])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear how to calculate the conversion but you can change that in this answer. I would recommend using the `apply` function.

Step 1:
Create dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'date': ['2019-02-21','2019-02-22', '2019-02-23', '2019-02-24','2019-02-21','2019-02-22', '2019-02-23', '2019-02-24'], 'device': ['desktop', 'desktop','desktop','desktop', 'other','other','other','other' ],
     'event1': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'event2': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Step 2:
Groupby date and device

```
df2=df.groupby(['device','date']).sum()
```

Step 3:
Calculate conversion

```
df2['outcome']=df2.apply(lambda x: 0 if ((df2['event1']==1).sum())==0
                         else (0 if x['event1']==0 else x['event2'] / x['event1']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tox, I feel like that is close to what I am trying to accomplish but not quite. If I run the function I have defined above to get the conversions, I get different results.

To clarify:
Conversion is equal to the number of users that have "1" in event1 and "1" in event2 divided by users that have "1" only in event 1.  See the line:
```conversion = len(current_df[(current_df[e1] == 1) & (current_df[e2] == 1)]) /len(current_df[current_df[e1] == 1]) 
```

Also, to avoid division by 0, I specify that converision is 0 if number of users that have "1" in event 1 is 0

Comment: `usersEvent1 = df2['event1'].sum()` and than `df2['outcome']=df2.apply(lambda x: ((x['event1']+x['event2'])/(usersEvent1)) if x['event1']==1 and x['event2']==1 else 0, axis=1)` can solve that?

Comment: Thanks again @Tox. It does not yet, your solution seems to be looking at isolated rows. 

I liked your dummy example and updated my question with an extended version of it. You can run the code and see that the results differ. See if it makes more sense now.

Comment: Cool! That seems to do it! Thanks!